# Handle "unknown column in field list" error for mySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am creating a PHP application for my company and I am using about 50+ checkboxes to allow the user to select what parts of the table they want to pull. However, right now, if the user selects a checkbox that has a corresponding SQL column name that is NOT in the table, there is no handle (it only returns 0 columns). Is there a way to handle this kind of problem easily? Thanks

Comment: This is kinda vague. Can you give more details?

Comment: I just want to handle the error that arises when you run a SELECT query on a database where one or more of the field names in the query are NOT columns in the database. I want to basically tell the user what checkbox is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't give the users options that are not available, in the first place.

But if you want to check a table structure in SQL, use `DESCRIBE tablename` as a query, then loop through the results looking at column `Field`. You should do that before constructing the SQL query that will get your actual data, so you don't reference any non-existent columns.

Comment: Also, I would like to not give the users options that are not available but I am not sure how that can be easily done since the different fields depend on what table is being searched by the user. So they user would basically have to type in the tablename first and THEN populate the checkboxes. My guess is this could be done with AJAX so I can populate the checkboxes without having to refresh the page in any way

Comment: @MattHintzke I'm glad my answer helped you! It is possible to show the checkboxes conditionally as you say, with ajax, but ajax is not required. You can also sent all possible options, for all tables, at once to the page, then use javascript to show/hide certain options depending on the table chosen. But this is beyond the scope of this question, so if you have any doubts in the process, I suggest you ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not give a checkbox name the name that the column is in the table. NEVER. Give them number if you want or different name or whatever, but inside the PHP script that receive the data, you must parse all the results.

Example :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fakeusername" value="true" />

$Username = (isset($_POST['fakeusername']) ? ($_POST['fakeusername'] == 'true' ? true : false) : false);

$Column = array();
if($Username === true){
    $Column[] = '`username`';
}
```

Comment: If you are saying not to name the checkbox name the same as the column in the table because of security reasons then I don't think it will be that much of a problem. The application is not available to the public. It is only a tool for use by a select few within this company so I don't think any of them will attempt to "hack" my code. That is why I didn't bother hiding it. If its not that, then why is it? Im curious. Also, Looking at your code, I do not quite understand what you are doing there. Thanks

Comment: @MattHintzke Yes, it was about security. My code was simply an example of "how to hide column name". If you say your application is okay to be non-securited then it's ok I guess. Question: Why you accepted my answer as accepted if she's not ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but are you basically checking to see if the checkbox is checked using the value and if it is, setting a value (SQL field name) to the array? Could this also be done by checking the "checked" attribute of the input?

Comment: oh ha, I didn't mean to. miss-clicked at some point. Thanks for reply though

Comment: @MattHintzke Yes, I check if the element is checked and if yes, `$Username = true`

Comment: never say NEVER, maybe you are working on opensource code and database structure is public...